# Why the two alerts are showing different values here? What's happening?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, scope

Consider the below JavaScript code:

```js
var x = 3;
var foo = {
  x: 2,
  baz: {
    x: 1,
    bar: function() {
      return this.x;
    }
  }
}
var go = foo.baz.bar;
alert(go());
alert(foo.baz.bar());
```

The two `alert`s here show different values. First one gives "3" and second one "1". But aren't both actually referring the same thing? I think its somehow related to the scope, but I am not getting it how the code is executing here.

Comment: what this means in js depends on context of the caller.

Comment: var go = foo.baz.bar it stores then function in the variable and as a you have declare X globally as 3 and locally as 3 value in your snippet. So, when you run alert((go()) it access global value of x and that is why it shows x = 3 in first alert. You may access foo.baz object's bar method and baz have property x also defined with value 1 so in that function this.x refers local object baz's property x.

Comment: @JonasW Nice duplicate find!

Comment: @bergi wasnt me, someone with low rep commented here, i just hit the close button ;)

Answer (score 0):

Context (basically `this`) is not defined by *where a function is* (in contrast to scope) but rather *how it is called*. Namingly when you do:

```
object.method()
```

`method` is called in `object`s context. When you do

```
method()
```

`method` is called in no context at all ( or in non strict mode it is `window` for some reason). However you can change that by *binding* the context:

```
var method = object.method.bind(object);
method();
```

Comment: Seems inconsistent to answer *and* close a question. By closing it, and thereby preventing people from answering, you're implying that it shouldn't be answered. By answering, you're giving it legitimacy, so why prevent others from doing the same?

Comment: You really should post your answer on the exact duplicate question, if you feel a new answer is necessitated at all.

Comment: @skinny pete well actually i answered and found the dupe later on. However i get your point. If you think i should delete this answer, let me know and i do so. However i think no one really profits from it when i delete it, its just waste of my time :)